# Blank screen on some user devices. No crash reports. Can't replicate the bug - how to fix it?

Tags: iphone

I released an iPhone/iPad app some weeks ago. From 15 reviews (worldwide) I got a dozen 1 star reviews from users saying the app does not work, they only get a blank screen. The other three are happy and it works for them.

I tested the app on an iPad 1, an iPad 2, an iPhone 3GS and several iPhone 4s - it worked on every device flawlessly. And it passed the app store submission process, so it must have worked at Apple...

The crash report in iTunes Connect is empty - the app obviously does not crash, it just hangs somewhere.

Unfortunately there is no way to contact the users where it doesn't work :-(

I know its really hard to help with that less information, but I don't know what to do when I can't replicate the problem on my side...

So does anybody has any idea?

If its a memory problem - shouldn't the app crash then?

I use AVFoundation to play a movie and I know of some flaws since its a relatively new library - does somebody know of this problem (a blank screen) in relation with AVFoundation?

It would be helpful as well if you could download the app (the name is "Hyperactive") and test if you get a blank screen. If so I would be glad to learn the exact device and the iOS version. I hope this is not missunderstood as spam, thats not what I intend...

Thanks in advance,

best regards,

Walchy

Comment: there are no magicians around here.. Describe what your app does or better yet, post some code..

Comment: You are right. I added the relevant startup code of my view controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the black screen only happens on an iPod Touch and the solution is very easy:

You need an additional entry in the .plist file for the iPod Touch:

Main nib file base name     ...

[iPod Touch 4G thinks it's an iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476294/ipod-touch-4g-thinks-its-an-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot, but maybe the user had the application running for a long time, receiving a `viewDidUnload`, and something you unload is not getting reloaded on the `viewDidLoad`.

Try running a "Simulate Memory Warning" on the iphone simulator options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reviews say sth. like "App won't work at all" - "Won't work. All I see is darkness", so it sounds like it does not start up at all... Tried the simulator memory warning - log says: "2011-08-28 22:44:34.405 Hyperactive[32241:207] Received simulated memory warning." but app still works...

Answer (score 0):

Both iPhone and iPad versions work fine on iPad 1.
Application won't install on iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1.

Have you tested your application on a jailbroken device?

Comment: Thanks for testing. The AVFoundation stuff only works on 3GS+, so I compiled it with armv7 only. It shouldn't load on armv6 devices at all... Yep, I tested it on one jailbroken iPad 1 and one jailbroken iPhone 4 - works on both...

Comment: Could it be iAd problem? I see iPhone sized banner on iPad. Clicked it - says 'connecton terminated'.

Comment: I don't think so. The reviews say: "Blank screen/Won't work at all" - I think they don't complain about a banner not working...